# PHP Remove empty value from array with unset not working correctly

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have a string containing sentences. I wish to break these sentences into an array, then modify each array item, including removing any array items that are empty.

Here's what I have:

```
//Explode string by dot
$items_array = explode(".", $raw_data);

//Loop through the array
foreach ($items_array as $i => $item) {

  //Remove any whitespace at front of item
  $item= ltrim($item);

  //Check if array item is empty and unset
  if($item === NULL){
    unset($items_array[$i]); 
  }

  //Reinstate the dot
  $item .= '.';
}
```

However, this does not work. I see extra '.' and if I put a `print(strlen($item));` within the loop (after the unset) I see a few `0` results.

I know the if condition is being met because if I put a print in there it will trigger the same amount of times a 0 appears, eg:

```
 if($item === NULL){
      print("no value");
      unset($raw_inclusions[$i]); 
    }
```

Have I done something wrong here?

Example $raw_data string. Assume I have no control over what is placed here.

```
$raw_data = "Brown fox. Lazy dog."
```

Expected/desired result:

```
$items_array = array("Brown fox.", "Lazy dog.");
```

Current result:

```
$items_array = array("Brown fox.", "Lazy dog.", ".");
```

Comment: give us an example of you have and what you expect the program to do.

Comment: @mbouzahir added above

Comment: `$item` will always be a string after `$item= ltrim($item);` so afterwards `$item === NULL` can never be true.  The line `$item .= '.';` at the end of the loop has no impact on `$items_array` unless you loop using a reference, i.e. `as &$item`.

Comment: @faintsignal gotta be honest here, I'm having trouble understanding. Sure so ltrim would turn it into a string, even if it's empty. Then shouldnt the if statement work if I use `strlen($item) == 0` wouldn't that work?

Comment: @MeltingDog That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy, you are just missing 1 line of code

Your Code

```
if($item === NULL){
    unset($items_array[$i]); 
}
//Reinstate the dot
$item .= '.';
```

Make it this

```
if($item === NULL){
    unset($items_array[$i]); 
}
else // <- The else is important
//Reinstate the dot
   $item .= '.';
```

And you need this line

```
$items_array[$i] = $item;
```

for anything to work (including your original code)

Answer (score 0):

**It is unclear what you want to achieve, but following may help you further.**

```
$raw_data = "Brown fox. Lazy dog.";
$items_array = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-z0-9])/i', $raw_data);

$sentences = new ArrayIterator($items_array);
for ($sentences->rewind(); $sentences->valid(); $sentences->next()) {
  // Do something with sentence
  print $sentences->current() . "\n";
}
```

And your approach to work it should look something like

```
//Explode string by dot
$items_array = explode(".", $raw_data);

//Loop through the array and pass sentence by reference
foreach ($items_array as $i => &$item) {

  //Remove any whitespace at front of item
  $item = ltrim($item);

  //Check if array item is empty and unset (and continue)
  if(empty($item)){
    unset($items_array[$i]);
    continue;
  }
  // Reinstate the dot
  $item .= '.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
$items_array = array_map(function($v) { return ltrim($v).'.'; },
                         array_filter(explode('.', $raw_data)));
```

- explode on `.`
- filter empty items
- map each item to trim and add `.`